# What are components for?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

First things first, What I love about Final Fantasy XIII is to be able to upgrade weapons/accessories using components. Can I do this with Final Fantasy XIII-2 like in the prequel?
I know I can use components to purchase weapons from Chocolina, all I'm asking is if I can actually upgrade my gear.

Comment: I recall being able to upgrade equipment into newer ones.  I don't remember if you can upgrade their attack stats, though.

Comment: Okay guys chill, i'm new here, i thought it was a bug or something.

Comment: (I commented above but deleted it when the line was edited out.) But yea. I do recall being able to upgrade equipment. It's been a while though so I don't remember the exact mechanics of it.

Comment: After reading the edits, I'd like to welcome you to Arqade, then just quickly explain that this site is not the same as most forums you can find around the place. This is a Q&A forum, so most "discussion-y" type aspects like "Welcomes myself" and "please don't come here to discuss things", have no place here. You can have a read through the [help centre](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) if you have any other questions about this. Again, Welcome to Arqade! I hope you enjoy your stay :)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently Final Fantasy XIII-2 doesn't allow weapon upgrades the way Final Fantasy XIII did. The closest it comes is to upgrading is that in order to buy certain powerful weapons, you need to trade in a certain other weapon in addition to other components. In that sense you're upgrading the weapon.

I haven't played Final Fantasy XIII-2, so I'm basing this on a [Game FAQs post](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/619315-final-fantasy-xiii-2/answers/311881-weapon-upgrades) and [Wikia's List of Final Fantasy XIII-2 Weapons](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Final_Fantasy_XIII-2_Weapons).